# Is it possible to limit the permissions on a per procedure basis?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a sql procedure where almost everything will be dynamic including selecting, grouping, ordering by, and where clauses using IN statements. In terms of code reuse, readability, and maintenance it makes a lot of sense to just pass in an sql query as a string and execute it. I am writing my procedure right now so that all the relevant data is joined and formatted in a static query and then inserted into a table variable. I then want to pass in sql queries to be executed against the table variable.

This opens me up to sql injection in a big way. I could create table value parameters for each of the many parameter types I am passing in but I don't want to do that. What I would really like to be able to do sandbox my procedure in a such a way that, on the procedure level, it is only possible to do these things I want to allow; ie select from certain tables, but not grant permissions or anything funny like that. Can this be done?

Comment: *In terms of code reuse, readability, and maintenance it makes a lot of sense to just pass in an sql query as a string and execute it.* **I strongly disagree.**

Comment: Start with reading these links: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html and http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Not much screams "maintenance nightmare" louder than a stored procedure that's genericized to "do everything".

Comment: Try using dynamic SQL inside the Proc instead of trying to make a "super" procedure. Or make a Proc that calls a proc that calls a proc. that shouls reduce your sql injection problem however anyway you look at solving this the way you are doing is going to be nightmare to maintain.

Comment: If I use dynamic sql in the procedure I can't use paramerterized dynamic sql, because I don't know the number of parameters ahead of time. Which only leaves generic EXEC, which does not provide any protections. The procedure is for a report, where the report parameters are very flexible. Hence the "do everything". The compromises I have to make all revolve around making the code much more static. Looks like it is what I have to do, but given safe alternative I would much rather generate the sql stringg.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be done.  It's a simple matter of programming.  You would keep rules in tables, and write logic in your stored procedure to query the rules tables, and follow the rules.

It will be a monumental job that will basically amount to you writing custom code to do what SQL Server already does for you if you don't use a generic, dynamic stored procedure.

I wouldn't do it, but you don't have to let that stop you.